# Linear subspaces of $\operatorname{GF}(3)^3$ containing a certain subspace.

Tags: linear-algebra, elementary-set-theory, vector-spaces, finite-fields

Let $\operatorname{GF}(3)$ be the Galois field with $3$ elements so that $\operatorname{GF}(3)\cong\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$.

Consider the vector space $\operatorname{GF}(3)^3$. Obviously, this vector space has $3^3$ vectors.

Let $u := (1, 0, 0)\in\operatorname{GF}(3)^3$.

How to determine all linear subspaces of $\operatorname{GF}(3)^3$ that contain $u$?

(I don't want to name each of them but I want to characterize them)

Comment: They are in bijective correspondence with the linear subspaces of the quotient space $\operatorname{GF}(3)^3/\operatorname{span}(u)$.

Comment: Thanks, that is good to know. But this is not a 'satisfying' characterization for me. I want to have it more concrete.

Comment: Alternatively, there is clearly only one $1$-dimensional and one $3$-dimensional linear subspace containing $u$, and the $2$-dimensional subspaces are parametrized by $\Bbb{P}^1(\operatorname{GF}(3))$, i.e. non-zero pairs $(x,y)\in\operatorname{GF}(3)^2$ up to scalar multiple.

Comment: Thanks. What does parametrized mean and what ist $\mathbb{P}^1$?

Comment: Thanks for editing your comment. Now everything is clear. You have completely answered my question ;-D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\Bbb{F}_3$ denote the field of three elements and $U$ the span of $u:=(1,0,0)$. The linear map
$$q:\ \Bbb{F}_3^3\ \longrightarrow\ \Bbb{F}_3^2:\ (a,b,c)\ \longmapsto\ (b,c),$$
yields a bijection between linear subspaces of $\Bbb{F}_3^2$ and linear subspaces of $\Bbb{F}_3^3$ containing $\ker q=U$. Explicitly, the linear subspaces of $\Bbb{F}_3^2$ with their corresponding subspaces of $\Bbb{F}_3^3$ are:
\begin{eqnarray*}
0\qquad&&\text{ corresponds with }\qquad q^{-1}(0)=U,\\
\langle(1,0)\rangle\qquad&&\text{ corresponds with }
\qquad q^{-1}(\langle(1,0)\rangle)=\langle u,(0,1,0)\rangle,\\
\langle(1,1)\rangle\qquad&&\text{ corresponds with }
\qquad q^{-1}(\langle(1,1)\rangle)=\langle u,(0,1,1)\rangle,\\
\langle(1,2)\rangle\qquad&&\text{ corresponds with }
\qquad q^{-1}(\langle(1,2)\rangle)=\langle u,(0,1,2)\rangle,\\
\langle(0,1)\rangle\qquad&&\text{ corresponds with }
\qquad q^{-1}(\langle(0,1)\rangle)=\langle u,(0,0,1)\rangle,\\
\Bbb{F}_3^2\qquad&&\text{ corresponds with }
\qquad q^{-1}(\Bbb{F}_3^2)=\Bbb{F}_3^3.
\end{eqnarray*}